# How to calculate VuMark width while uploading to Vuforia Target Manager?

Tags: ios, vuforia

I have been working on one Augmented Reality demo in which I am using Vuforia 7 SDK for my iOS App.I want to use VuMark as Target and for that I have one svg File with my VuMark Design.

Now, When I am uploadig this svg on Target Manager it shows processing for a while and then it ends with failed status.

I assume that there might be something wrong with width parameter or I might be doing it wrong.please help me if someone knows about it,Thanks.